# Displaying entries of an index (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to list all the entries of an index.
Let's say I have unique `index_idx` on 2 columns (col_1, col_2) on table `table_test`.
I assume that the uniqueness for a tuple is checked by concatenating the values in column `col1` and `col2` and checking if overall the value is unique.
But is there any method predefined using which we can list all the entries for index `index_idx`.

I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41348484). But the answer didn't make much sense to me. What exactly is ''INDEX COLUMNS LIST' here?

Comment: I just fixed the link, by deleting `https://` which was mentioned twice....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to query and display rows of an Index table (MySql DBMS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303810/how-to-query-and-display-rows-of-an-index-table-mysql-dbms)

Comment: I think `INDEX COLUMNS LIST` is referring to the list of columns which are used in the index. In your case `col_1` and `col_2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way directly to list the contents of an index (the MySQL / MariaDB developers may have a way to dump index contents, but if they do it's for debugging purposes).

`SELECT col_1, col_2 FROM table_test` gets you the contents of the index. The index you mentioned is a so-called [covering index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_covering_index) for that query.  MySQL uses the index, rather than the table, to satisfy the query. That's a little faster.

The [item you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303810/how-to-query-and-display-rows-of-an-index-table-mysql-dbms/41348484#41348484) does this same thing.

And you are basically correct that the uniqueness of a two-column UNIQUE index is determined with the concatenation of the column values.